# gt: error: neither tool nor script specified;

Tags: android, webrtc

I am trying to build an android version of webrtc.I am googled and find a [document](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/) .I followed all the steps and installed all required things as per the document but now I am stuck at the terminal command

`` echo export PATH="$PATH":`pwd`/depot_tools &gt;&gt; ~/.bashrc ``

It always give an error

```
gt: error: neither tool nor script specified;
```

Is there any other documentation for android webrtc?

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

The intention is to add something to your path.

Using `>>` you can append to a file. E.g.

`echo "Add this to an existing file" >> existing.txt`

`&gt;` is a way to specify `>` in HTML, XML, etc, in order to avoid it being interpreted as the closing angle bracket of a `<tag>`. In this tutorial `>` is incorrectly shown as `&gt;`. Have a look at "HTML escape characters" or [HTML character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) for more information.

Putting this together, what you actually want to do, is:

`` echo export PATH="$PATH":`pwd`/depot_tools >> ~/.bashrc ``